# Using List from one method into another

Tags: java, robotframework

```
private List<String> add() {
    List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    return strList;
}

public void methodOne() {
    List<String> strList = this.add();
}

public void methodtwo() {
    // need to use the list in methodOne.
}
```

I have one private method which returns a `List`. I executed that `add()` method by calling it in `methodOne()` and stored List values. Now I need to use that List in `methodTwo()` method without executing either `add()` method or `methodOne()`.
Methods are nothing but Keywords in RobotFrame Work

Is it possible to create a `List` variable in Ride and store the List from `Method One()` and use it in `Method Two()` ?

Comment: these are all locally defined list´s, if you can´t use `add`, this wont work. The `List` in `methodOne` is also locally defined, so if you don´t return a `List<String>` nor store it in any variable with a different scope than `methodOne` this `List` will be garbage collected pretty soonish let aside that you can never refer to it.

Comment: That's a weird thing you're asking from the perspective of someone used to Java. Can you explain why you want to work with the same list in `methodtwo` as in `methodOne` ? A solution would be to use a class member instead of a local variable if you want multiple functions to work on the same object by mutating it. However, the initialisation you do in your `add` method then probably makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create class level list so that when method one execute it, it populate class level variable, so that you can use it in methodTwo()

Answer (score 2):

```
public class YourClass{

    private List<String> yourList;

    private List<String> add(){
        List<String> strlist=new ArrayList<String>();
        return strList;
    }

    public void methodOne(){
        yourList=this.add();
    }

    public void methodtwo(){
        // here go with yourList variable.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify `methodOne()` so that it returns that list instead of void

```
public List<String> methodOne() {
    List<String> strList = this.add(); 
    .... something else....
    return strList;
}

public void methodtwo() {
    methodOne(); // here you get a ref to strList...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void methodOne(){
    List<String> strList=this.add();
}
```

With the above piece of code, **you can not use strList** anywhere else from methodOne because it's a local list whose scope is not outside this method.

You have 2 options left,

```
Option1:
public List<String> methodOne(){
    List<String> strList=this.add();
    // do SomeOperation on strList because that's why methodOne is there else you can directly call add method from methodTwo()
    return strList;
}

public void methodtwo(){
  List<String> myLocalList = methodOne(); // Now you have the list :)
}


Option2: Use Instance level list but it's not a good practice
```